# Javascript API to screen scrape page flow, including button click

Tags: javascript, selenium, screen-scraping

We are looking for Javascript API to screen scrape page flow, including button click. If it were on server side, WebDriver of Selenium would have been a great choice, but we want the screen scraping to run on the client browser. The screens to be scrapped is a transaction in itself (login to third party website, transaction step 1, step 2 and then final confirmation). Any javascript API available?

AFAIK, both nodeJS and phantom JS don't have capability to click a button from the scrapped page.

thanks in advance,
abbas

Answer (score 1):

Webdriver is an HTTP based protocol, something that every browser speaks, so it is possible to control one browser from another. I've written a tutorial some weeks ago on that topic [here](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/tutorials/WebDriver)

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into DalekJS (http://dalekjs.com/docs/actions.html) which allows for taking screenshots of pages and clicking on the elements as well. I think it even supports multiple browsers -- although they have to be installed (http://dalekjs.com/pages/documentation.html#browsers).

here is the sample code directly from the link:

```
 test.open('http://doctorwhotv.co.uk/')
 .assert.text('#nav').is('Navigation')
 .assert.visible('#nav')
 .assert.attr('#nav', 'data-nav', 'true')
 .click('#nav')
 .done();
```

Comment: But the problem with Dalekjs is that it needs to run with a dalek framework. We require some tool (eg. js file) that we can bundle inside our webpage and runs in the browser.

Comment: I'm not sure then. I'll look harder when I get the chance.